# Selendroid scroll issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, selendroid

Using appium-selendroid mode on my real device running Android API level 17, I try to scroll down using the following code

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver).scroll(0,100);
action.perform();
```

The scrolling takes place however, The elements do not get rendered.Kindly help to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - implement a class that uses the interface RemoteWebDriver
    public class SwipeableWebDriver extends RemoteWebDriver implements HasTouchScreen {
    public RemoteTouchScreen touch;

```
public SwipeableWebDriver(URL url, Capabilities caps) {
    super(url, caps);
    touch = new RemoteTouchScreen(getExecuteMethod());
}

public TouchScreen getTouch() {
    return touch;
}
```

Now instantiate a driver of this class and use the Touch class as given in the question with the "flick" gesture rather than scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I was using same code and was facing same issue and after using flick method it was fixed for me. [Already answered here](http://asktofolks.com/806/selendroid-scroll-does-not-update-content)

Don't use scroll just replace it with flick and you also have to give an element address with flick.

> TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver).flick(element_add, 0,
>   -1000, 100); action.perform();